# How to stop oracle listening on port 1521(TNS)

Tags: vb.net, oracle, tns

There is a oracle xe edition installed on a machine.
My requirement is to stop oracle from listening on the 1521 port.
This port is used by the TNS system.
Also i need to do this from a vb.net program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is call [`lsnrctl`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/lsnrctl.htm), the utility from Oracle that manages the listeners.

You can call it with [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
startInfo.FileName = "lsnrctl"
startInfo.Arguments = "stop"
startInfo.Verb = "runas"
Process.Start(startInfo)
```

You set the `Verb` to `runas` to make it run as administrator.

In order to make this work, you should have the Oracle bin folder in your `PATH`. Note that calling this will make your Oracle installation unavailable from the outside since the listeners control the access to Oracle databases.

Comment: So how does this stop oracle from listening on the 1521 port ?

Comment: You stop the listener... :)

Comment: "lsnrctl" is the Listener Control Utility and the commands seem to stop the utility. Please correct me if i am wrong , but i think you are saying that the above command is going to stop the listener completely.

Comment: Yes. So no listeners any more on port 1521. That is what you wanted, right?

Comment: So stopping the utility stops the listener ? Hmm interesting. i though i need to use the utility to send commands to stop a certain listener.Can you please point me to a link that explains this in more detail.

Comment: No, you don't stop the utility. You tell it to stop the listener.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60530/discussion-between-som-bhattacharyya-and-patrick-hofman).

Comment: Just a last question. If the machine is restarted would the stopped listener(s) remain stopped ?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya: Why did you unaccept? Anything wrong with my post?

Comment: i just tried it and the settings do not hold after a restart so i believe after the stopping the listener i need to change the port number in the files Oracle_HOME\network\admin\listener.ora and tnsnames.ora any idea on what do i write in the port number area and how to do that from the vb.net code ?

Answer (score 1):

Find the file called listener.ora (Oracle_HOME\network\admin\listener.ora).
This file has the parameters for your listener. 
Change the port number. Save the changes. Restart your listener.

To connect properly to your database you may need to change the port number in your tnsnames.ora accordingly.

Comment: So if i want to makle sure that all external database requests are blocked i just remove the port numbers (default 1521) from the file ?

Comment: No, this just changes the port number. Your original question is not very clear on that point.

Comment: Okay so let me try and restate the problem , i have a program that installs oracle xe as part of the install process. Now at the end of the install process i want to stop this oracle instance(used by my application) from listening on the 1521 port. i need to do this via the vb.net code my application is built on.

Comment: If you stop the listener will your application still work? Alternatively. On a standard windows installation the firewall already blocks port 1521.

Comment: The thing is i have people using Unix systems as well so cant bank on windows firewall. Yes if i block the listener the app will still work since the entire vb.net app and the database are installed on the same machine.

Comment: i just tried it and the settings do not hold after a restart
so i believe after the stopping the listener i need to change the port number in the files Oracle_HOME\network\admin\listener.ora and tnsnames.ora
any idea on what do i write in the port number area and how to do that from the vb.net code ?